# Close open popup on backkey press in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1.1

In my application I am using a popup in a page. When I press on back key, I need to close the popup if it is open and stay on the page. When I pressed on the back key, the popup not closed and the page goes to previous one. To close the popup now I use the following code in the `back key press event.`

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (myPopup.IsOpen)
        myPopup.IsOpen = false;

    else if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

When using this code, the popup will close but also goes to the previous page. I need to go back only if popup is in closed state. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Instead of using

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I used the `back key press event` of the page

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (myPopup.IsOpen)
        myPopup.IsOpen = false;

    else if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (myPopup.IsOpen)
    {
    myPopup.IsOpen = false;
    e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```